# Testcafe: Evaluators/debugger for Selectors

Tags: debugging, testing, automated-tests, selector, testcafe

Is there a better way to evaluate selectors? Currently, when TestCafe does not find a selector the error message is not helpful every time. Is there a way to evaluate/assess valid selectors or debug selectors. This will help expedite the test writing process

Answer (score 2):

At present, the best way to debug TestCafe's Selectors includes two steps:

- find a method in chain after which the selector no longer matches any DOM element. (see the [Debug Selectors](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/test-api/selecting-page-elements/selectors/using-selectors.html#debug-selectors) help topic)
- output the element's outerHTML value of the previous method call in the chain.

```js
    import { Selector } from 'testcafe';

    fixture `Fixture`
        .page('https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/example/');

    test('test', async t => {
        const selector = Selector('fieldset').addCustomDOMProperties({
            outerHTML: el => el.outerHTML
        });

        console.log(await selector.outerHTML);
    });
```

Comment: Thanks @mlosev I was hoping there was an easier way to do this. But it seems this is the only way. :(